# Why can I seemingly define a partial specialization for function templates?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I know that the below code is a partial specialization of a class:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
class MyClass { 
  … 
}; 


// partial specialization: both template parameters have same type 
template <typename T> 
class MyClass<T,T> { 
  … 
};
```

Also I know that C++ does not allow function template partial specialization (only full is allowed). But does my code mean that I have partially specialized my function template for one/same type arguments? Because it works for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express! If no, then could you please explain the partial specialization concept?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T1, typename T2> 
inline T1 max (T1 const& a, T2 const& b) 
{ 
    return a < b ? b : a; 
} 

template <typename T> 
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return 10;
}


int main ()
{
    cout << max(4,4.2) << endl;
    cout << max(5,5) << endl;
    int z;
    cin>>z;
}
```

Comment: Look for that analogy of class specialization. If it is called class specialization, then why I should consider the same thing for function as overloading??

Comment: No, specialization syntax is different. Look at the (supposed) function specialization syntax in my answer below.

Comment: Why doesn't this throw a "Call to max is ambigious" error? How does `max(5,5)` resolve to `max(T const&, T const&) [with T=int]` and not `max(T1 const&, T2 const&) [with T1=int and T2=int]`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Function partial specialization is **not allowed** yet as per the standard. In the example, you are actually **overloading & not specializing** the `max<T1,T2>` function.
Its *syntax* should have looked *somewhat* like below, had it been allowed:

```
// Partial specialization is not allowed by the spec, though!
template <typename T> 
inline T const& max<T,T> (T const& a, T const& b)
{            //    ^^^^^ <--- supposed specializing here as an example
  return a; // can be anything of type T
}
```

In the case of a function templates, **only full specialization** is allowed by the C++ standard.
There are some compiler extensions which allows partial specialization, but the code looses its portability in such case!

Comment: It is not allow because it could confuse the compiler for confusing the right specialized version of the function, no? If it is true, the what will be confusing for compiler if the function was not overloaded by the way I have written but it was specialized by the way you have written (in a not allowed way)?

Comment: @Narek, Partial function specialization is not part of standard (for whatsoever reasons). I think MSVC supports it as an extension. May be after sometime, it would be allowed by other compilers also.

Comment: @Nawaz, no problem, In the last line I actually wanted to mention as `in the case of *classes* only **specialization** is allowed` (as overloading is meant only for functions). However I missed `classes` and messed up the sentence.

Comment: @iammilind: No problem. He already seems to know that. That is why he is trying that for function template as well. So I edited it again, making it clear now.

Comment: Anyone who can explain _why_ partial specialization isn't allowed?

Comment: Why doesn't this throw a "Call to max is ambigious" error? How does `max(5,5)` resolve to `max(T const&, T const&) [with T=int]` and not `max(T1 const&, T2 const&) [with T1=int and T2=int]`?

Comment: @NHDaly, It doesn't give ambiguity error because 1 function is better match than the other. Why it selects `(T, T)` over `(T1, T2)` for `(int, int)`, is because the former guarantees that there are 2 parameters and both types are same; the latter only guarantees that there are 2 parameters. Compiler chooses always an accurate description. e.g. If you have to make a choice between 2 descriptions of a "River" which one would you choose? "collection of water" vs "collection of Water flowing".

Comment: Does the standard explicitly prohibit partial spec or does it simply not specify it?

Comment: @kfsone, I think this feature is under review, hence open for interpretation. You may refer [this open-std section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40652694/514235), which I saw in [Why does the C++ standard not allow function template partial specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40652694/514235)

Answer (score 58):

Since partial specialization is not allowed -- as other answers pointed --, you could work around it using `std::is_same` and `std::enable_if`, as below:

```
template <typename T, class F>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, void>::type
typed_foo(const F& f) {
    std::cout << ">>> messing with ints! " << f << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, class F>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value, void>::type
typed_foo(const F& f) {
    std::cout << ">>> messing with floats! " << f << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    typed_foo<int>("works");
    typed_foo<float>(2);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
>>> messing with ints! works
>>> messing with floats! 2
```

---

**Edit**: In case you need to be able to treat all the other cases left, you could add a definition which states that already treated cases should not *match* -- otherwise you'd fall into ambiguous definitions. The definition could be:

```
template <typename T, class F>
inline typename std::enable_if<(not std::is_same<T, int>::value)
    and (not std::is_same<T, float>::value), void>::type
typed_foo(const F& f) {
    std::cout << ">>> messing with unknown stuff! " << f << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    typed_foo<int>("works");
    typed_foo<float>(2);
    typed_foo<std::string>("either");
}
```

Which produces:

```
$ ./a.out 
>>> messing with ints! works
>>> messing with floats! 2
>>> messing with unknown stuff! either
```

Although this *all-cases* thing looks a bit boring, since you have to tell the compiler everything you've already done, it's quite doable to treat up to 5 or a few more specializations.

Comment: There really isn't any need to do this as this can be handled by function overloading in a much simpler and clearer fashion.

Comment: @Adrian I really can't think of any other function overloading approach to solve this. You noticed partial overloading is not allowed, right? Share with us your solution, if you think it is clearer.

Comment: is there any other way to do **easily** catch all templated function?

Comment: @Adrian It is true one may in some cases redefine `typed_foo` in such a way that it only takes one template argument instead of two, and then use overloading like you said. However, this is not really what the OP was asking. And besides, I'm not sure if you could do a catch-all function purely with overloads. Also, you might _want_ your catch-all implementation to _cause a compile error when it is used_, which is only possible with template functions, where a template-dependent line would cause the compiler to issue an error.

Answer (score 19):

> What is specialization ?

If you really want to understand templates, you should take a look at functional languages. The world of templates in C++ is a purely functional sublanguage of its own.

In functional languages, selections are done using *Pattern Matching*:

```
-- An instance of Maybe is either nothing (None) or something (Just a)
-- where a is any type
data Maybe a = None | Just a

-- declare function isJust, which takes a Maybe
-- and checks whether it's None or Just
isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool

-- definition: two cases (_ is a wildcard)
isJust None = False
isJust Just _ = True
```

As you can see, we *overload* the definition of `isJust`.

Well, C++ class templates work exactly the same way. You provide a *main* declaration, that states the number and nature of the parameters. It can be just a declaration, or also acts as a definition (your choice), and then you can (if you so wish) provide specializations of the pattern and associate to them a different (otherwise it would be silly) version of the class.

For template functions, specialization is somewhat more awkward: it conflicts somewhat with overload resolution. As such, it has been decided that a specialization would relate to a non-specialized version, and specializations would not be considered during overload resolution. Therefore, the algorithm for selecting the right function becomes:

1. Perform overload resolution, among regular functions and non-specialized templates
2. If a non-specialized template is selected, check if a specialization exist for it that would be a better match

(for on in-depth treatment, see [GotW #49](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm))

As such, template specialization of functions is a second-zone citizen (literally). As far as I am concerned, we would be better off without them: I have yet to encounter a case where a template specialization use could not be solved with overloading instead.

> Is this a template specialization ?

No, it is simply an overload, and this is fine. In fact, overloads usually work as we expect them to, while specializations can be surprising (remember the GotW article I linked).

Comment: `"As such, template specialization of functions is a second-zone citizen (literally). As far as I am concerned, we would be better off without them: I have yet to encounter a case where a template specialization use could not be solved with overloading instead."` How about with non type template parameters?

Comment: @Julius: you can still use overloading, albeit by introducing a dummy parameter such as `boost::mpl::integral_c<unsigned, 3u>`. Another solution could also be to use `enable_if`/`disable_if`, though it's a different story.

Answer (score 11):

Non-class, non-variable partial specialization is not allowed, but as said:

> All problems in computer
>   science can be solved by
>   another level of indirection. —— David Wheeler

Adding a class to forward the function call can solve this, here is an example:

```
template <class Tag, class R, class... Ts>
struct enable_fun_partial_spec;

struct fun_tag {};

template <class R, class... Ts>
constexpr R fun(Ts&&... ts) {
  return enable_fun_partial_spec<fun_tag, R, Ts...>::call(
      std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}

template <class R, class... Ts>
struct enable_fun_partial_spec<fun_tag, R, Ts...> {
  constexpr static R call(Ts&&... ts) { return {0}; }
};

template <class R, class T>
struct enable_fun_partial_spec<fun_tag, R, T, T> {
  constexpr static R call(T, T) { return {1}; }
};

template <class R>
struct enable_fun_partial_spec<fun_tag, R, int, int> {
  constexpr static R call(int, int) { return {2}; }
};

template <class R>
struct enable_fun_partial_spec<fun_tag, R, int, char> {
  constexpr static R call(int, char) { return {3}; }
};

template <class R, class T2>
struct enable_fun_partial_spec<fun_tag, R, char, T2> {
  constexpr static R call(char, T2) { return {4}; }
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<int>(1, 1)), int>, "");
static_assert(fun<int>(1, 1) == 2, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<char>(1, 1)), char>, "");
static_assert(fun<char>(1, 1) == 2, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<long>(1L, 1L)), long>, "");
static_assert(fun<long>(1L, 1L) == 1, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<double>(1L, 1L)), double>, "");
static_assert(fun<double>(1L, 1L) == 1, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<int>(1u, 1)), int>, "");
static_assert(fun<int>(1u, 1) == 0, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<char>(1, 'c')), char>, "");
static_assert(fun<char>(1, 'c') == 3, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<unsigned>('c', 1)), unsigned>, "");
static_assert(fun<unsigned>('c', 1) == 4, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<unsigned>(10.0, 1)), unsigned>, "");
static_assert(fun<unsigned>(10.0, 1) == 0, "");

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<double>(1, 2, 3, 'a', "bbb")), double>, "");
static_assert(fun<double>(1, 2, 3, 'a', "bbb") == 0, "");

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(fun<unsigned>()), unsigned>, "");
static_assert(fun<unsigned>() == 0, "");
```

Comment: I don't want to hear my crazy idea does not work, or that the standard some crap. I want to hear that with enough effort it will work.

Answer (score 6):

I m sorry for the late answer, but i ve found a solution which i don't see explained (not directly at least) in the other answers.

A function cannot be *partially specialized*, while a class can.
What can do the trick here is a static function inside class.
We can make it works basically moving the "template partial specialization" inside a class specialization and creating inside it the function marked as static. This will allow us, by incrementing a bit the lines of code required, to construct our partially specialized function.

Let's consider the unavailable partially specialized function `Printer` as follow (**code which doesn't compile at all**).

```
template <class T, class Trait = void>
void Printer(const T&);

template <class T>
void Printer<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>(const T& v){
    std::cout << "I m partially specialized for any floating point type." << std::endl;
}
template <class T>
void Printer<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>(const T& v){
    std::cout << "I m partially specialized for any integral type." << std::endl;
}
```

We can make it works using static class functions and moving the partial specialization on class instead like this:

```
namespace detail{
    
    template<class T, class Trait = void>
    struct Specialized;

    template<class T>
    struct Specialized<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
    {
        static void Printer(const T& v){
            std::cout << "I m specialized for any floating point type"<< std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    struct Specialized<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
    {
        static void Printer(const T& v){
            std::cout << "I m specialized for any integral type"<< std::endl;
        }
    };
}


template<class T>
void Printer(const T& v)
{
    detail::Specialized<T>::Printer(v);   
}
```

It results a bit longer but would solve our issue with a relatively clear way.
You can test it on godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/z/f9hYn1Mjj).

------ EDIT : Thanks to [KROy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289483/kroy) for the hint

It can be made even shorter by just wrapping the two static functions inside a struct leaving the template specialization on them:

```
namespace detail{
    struct Specialized{
        template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0>
        static void Printer(const T& v){
            std::cout << "I'm specialized for integral types." << std::endl;
        }

        template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, int> = 0>
        static void Printer(const T& v){
            std::cout << "I'm specialized for floating point types." << std::endl;
        }
    };
}

template<class T>
void Printer(const T& v)
{
    detail::Specialized::Printer(v);   
}
```

It can be tested on godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/z/G9Eo6K7r5).

Comment: Just wrap the function around a struct and it will work. Check how std::Optional calls the dtor.

Comment: @KRoy Thank you for your tip, i've adjusted the answer

Answer (score 4):

No. For example, you can legally specialize `std::swap`, but you cannot legally define your own overload. That means that you cannot make `std::swap` work for your own custom class template.

Overloading and partial specialization can have the same effect in some cases, but far from all.

Comment: That's why you put your `swap` overload in your namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but some late readers might find it useful: Sometimes, a helper function – designed such that it can be specialised – can solve the issue, too.

So let's imagine, this is what we *tried* to solve:

```
template <typename R, typename X, typename Y>
void function(X x, Y y)
{
    R* r = new R(x);
    f(r, y); // another template function?
}

// for some reason, we NEED the specialization:
template <typename R, typename Y>
void function<R, int, Y>(int x, Y y) 
{
    // unfortunately, Wrapper has no constructor accepting int:
    Wrapper* w = new Wrapper();
    w->setValue(x);
    f(w, y);
}
```

OK, partial template function specialisation, we cannot do that... So let's "export" the part needed for specialisation into a helper function, specialize that one and use it:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
R* create(T t)
{
    return new R(t);
}
template <>
Wrapper* create<Wrapper, int>(int n) // fully specialized now -> legal...
{
    Wrapper* w = new Wrapper();
    w->setValue(n);
    return w;
}

template <typename R, typename X, typename Y>
void function(X x, Y y)
{
    R* r = create<R>(x);
    f(r, y); // another template function?
}
```

This *can* be interesting especially if the alternatives (normal overloads instead of specialisations, the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218271/1312382) proposed by Rubens, ... – not that these are bad or mine is better, just *another* one) would share quite a lot of common code.