# Overloading template function in cpp

Tags: c++, templates, matching

I have this hpp

```
namespace A
{
    template<class T>
    class MyC
    {
    public:
        T a;
    };

    template<class T>
    void F(T r);
}
```

and this cpp

```
template<>
void A::F<double>(double r)
{
    r;
}

template<>
void A::F<int>(int r)
{
    r;
}

template<class T>
void A::F<A::MyC<T>>(A::MyC<T> r)
{
    r;
}
template void A::F<A::MyC<int>>(A::MyC<int>);
template void A::F<A::MyC<double>>(A::MyC<double>);
```

but compiler says **"unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"** about F.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: on `A::F<A::MyC<T>>` right - the others are ok?

Comment: yep, other overloads are okay.

bad things happens only when we using template type like parameter for template function

Comment: You're not overloading in the cpp, but explicitly specializing and explicitly instantiating. `F`, being a function template, *is* a set of overloaded functions.

Comment: "Wrong" is that partial template specialization of a function is prohibited. F should be a class/struct for this to work. And yes, this is not overload but template specialization. You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061456/c-function-template-partial-specialization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put those declarations all in `namespace A { ... }` and remove `A::`. On the other hand, function template partial specialization is not allowed and this will make error:

```
template<class T>
void F<MyC<T>>(MyC<T> r)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to make this overloads without changing hpp file?