# C++ function template partial specialization error when overloading operator

Tags: c++, templates

I have checked this post [C++ function template partial specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061456/c-function-template-partial-specialization)

However, the following error is still confusing. Why does template-id not match the function declaration?

```
error: function template partial specialization ‘operator<< <T>’ is not allowed
 ostream& operator<< <T>( ostream& out, RBTree<T>& rbt)

error: template-id ‘operator<< <int>’ for ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, RBTree<int>&)’ does not match any template declaration
     friend ostream& operator<< <T>( ostream& out, RBTree<T>& rbt);
```

I am implementing the red-black tree with class RBTree for any input type T.

```
class RBTree{
    friend ostream& operator<< <T>( ostream& out, RBTree<T>& rbt);
public:
    RBTree(){ nil = new RBTreeNode<T>( BLACK ); root = nil; }
    .....
};


template<class T>
ostream& operator<< <T>( ostream& out, RBTree<T>& rbt)
{
    rbt.InOrder( rbt.GetRoot(), out );
    return out;
}
```

Comment: C++ does not allow you to partially specialize a function, you should remove the <T> before the function name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overloading friend operator<< for template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class)

Comment: @sangrey in fact c++ does not allow specializing a member function.

Answer (score 1):

The function that you're trying to implement is not a partial specialization, but rather an overload. As such you should not be attempting to use specialization syntax. Change your operator implementation to (note the absence of `<T>` following `operator<<` on second line):

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out, RBTree<T>& rbt)
{
    rbt.InOrder( rbt.GetRoot(), out );
    return out;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried remove the <T> following the operator <<, and the 1st error disappears. However, the 2nd error "template-id mismatch" is still there.

Comment: If your post all your *actual* code I might be able to help. What you shared so far would not produce this error