# Is there a way to partially specialize my templated function based on a lambda parameter return type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have written a templated function which is designed to accept a lambda and a pack of arguments. I have declared the return type of my function to be the return type of the lambda. Is there a way I can specialize my templated function for certain lambda parameter return types?

The working portion of my code is as follows:

```
template <typename F, typename ... T>
auto crudeProfile(F f, T ... args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {...}
```

This works as I would expect it to. But I’d like to specialize its behavior on lambdas that return void. I have only so far come up with the following code:

```
template <typename F, typename ... T>
void crudeProfile(F f, T ... args) {...}
```

But the compiler complains about this when I try to use it:

```
1>Source.cpp(684): error C2668: 'crudeProfile': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>  Source.cpp(637): note: could be 'void crudeProfile<main::<lambda_a7118596c99e3162db30942634c4e81e>,>(F)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=main::<lambda_a7118596c99e3162db30942634c4e81e>
1>          ]
1>  Source.cpp(624): note: or       'void crudeProfile<main::<lambda_a7118596c99e3162db30942634c4e81e>,>(F)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=main::<lambda_a7118596c99e3162db30942634c4e81e>
1>          ]
1>  Source.cpp(684): note: while trying to match the argument list '(main::<lambda_a7118596c99e3162db30942634c4e81e>)'
```

Even lambdas that return non-void result in this error, though the error will slightly change, to read "could be 'type' or void" (where 'type' is whatever the lambda return type is).

Comment: Do you have access to C++17?

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt for me to upgrade, but right now I believe I am on C++11— MSVC++ 2015, the macro __cplusplus == 199711

Comment: I think you can write your function identically even with return type void with appropriate RAII.

Comment: you could check the similar my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218849/2709407) to a similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to partially specialize my templated function?

No you can't, but there's a workaround.

> Probably wouldn't hurt for me to upgrade (to C++17) ...

So in C++17, thanks to `if constexpr`, you can write a very easy workaround for that without hurting your code too much as follows:

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
decltype(auto) crudeProfile(F f, Ts ... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, Ts...>, void>)
    {
        // void
    }
    else
    {
        // not void
    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough on VC2015 this compiles _only_ if I omit the `constexpr` portion of the if statement, change `is_same_v` to just `is_same`, and `invoke_result_t` to `result_of<T1,T2>::type`.  But it works!

Comment: @DavidRogers It might work without `constexpr`, but in that case you have to make sure the two implementations splitted by the *raw* `if` must be **NOT** ill-formed because the compiler tries to evaluate both, even if the control flow never meets the other condition. (Which is the significant difference between `if` and `if constexpr`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't partially specialize function templates and overloading is also out of the question<sup>1</sup>, so you have to resort on classes. Note that you can use `if constexpr` to simplify this a lot if you have access to C++17.

```
template <typename F, typename = void, typename... Ts>
struct helper {
    auto operator()(F f, Ts... args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {
      // your code
    }
};

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
struct helper<F, typename std::result_of<F(Ts...)>::type, Ts...> {
    void operator()(F f, Ts... args) {
        // specialization for void
    }
};

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
auto crudeProfile(F f, Ts... args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {
    return helper<F, Ts...>(f, args...);
}
```

Note: `std::result_of` was replaced by `std::invoke_result`, so if you can use that instead (C++17), use that instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that you can still use SFINAE, but I don't like this option, as that would require you to duplicate one binary condition (namely that the result of invoking `f(args...)` is a void).

If you want to do so instead of going through a helper, it is simply a matter of adding an additional template parameter to both overloads: `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<void, typename std::result_of<F(Ts...)>::type>::value>::type* = nullptr>`. Don't forget to remove the negation for the second overload.

Comment: @DeanSeo Oops, sorry about that. Forgot that there cannot be any template parameters after a variadic. Fixed