# Is there a particular reason why the C++ standard disallows partial templated function specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

I've read that it simplifies the compiler's job, but is there a deeper reason - like possibly breaking something else in the language?

Comment: I've heard it did not come to standard because concepts would do that better, but concepts then did not come for different reason

Comment: I'm trying to find a dupe but in the mean time: Since functions can be overloaded, you can just overload the function instead of needing to partially specialize it.  That could be the reason they didn't add it.

Comment: @NathanOliver wish granted

Comment: @Brian That isn't the best target.  All of the answers only contain guesses or possible reasons.  I'm trying to find a better one.

Comment: I really like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061811/4342498).  I'll add it as another dupe target.