# template specialization causes a undefined reference error

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I tried a template specialization like bellow.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 something(T2 a);

template<class T2>
double something(T2 a){
    double b;
    return b;
}

int main(){
    something<double, double>(0.0);
}
```

However, this gives me a compilatoin error:

```
In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `double something<double, double>(double)'
```

Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I can compile this exact code without error - are you sure this is **exactly** the code you are compiling? How are you compiling it?

Comment: @BoBTFish I am really sorry, I pasted different one. Now, I edited.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This is **not** specialization, it is actually **overloading**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061522/1171191

Comment: You are getting that error because you are calling a function (overload) that is declared but not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not template specialization, but [function template overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading).

The 1st overloading has two template parameters, the 2nd one has only one; when you call it with two specified template arguments like `something<double, double>(0.0);`, the 1st one will be selected in overload resolution; but it's not defined then leads to link error.

---

<sup>BTW: Function templates can only be [full specialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), they can't be [partial specialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). And in most cases [function template overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) would do the work well.</sup>