# C++ Template Specialization / Partial and Full

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I was trying to understand Template Partial and Full Specialization and have this below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Template in C++is a feature. We write code once and use it for any data type including user defined data types.
//What if we want a different code for a particular data type - Template Specialization
template <class T, class Y>
void fun(T a, Y b)
{
    cout << "The main template fun(): " << a << " " <<  b << endl;
}
//If a specialized version is present, compiler first checks with the specialized version and then the main template.
//Compiler first checks with the most specialized version by matching the passed parameter with the data type(s) specified in a specialized version.
template<>
void fun(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    cout << "Specialized Template for int type: " << a << " " <<  b << endl;
}
//Partial specialization allows to specialize only some arguments of a class template, as opposed to explicit full
template<class T>
void fun(T a, int b)
{
    cout << "Partial Template specialization for int type: " << a << " " << b << endl;
}
int main()
{
    fun<int, int>('a', 10);
    fun< const char*, const char*>("Hello", "Morning");
    fun<float, float>(10.14, 19.89);
}
```

Note that in main I am specifying the data types and below is the output:

```
The main template fun(): 97 10
Specialized Template for int type: Hello Morning
The main template fun(): 10.14 19.89
```

But when I execute the main code below way:

```
int main()
{
    fun('a', 10);
    fun("Hello", "Morning");
    fun(10.14, 19.89);
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Partial Template specialization for int type: a 10
Specialized Template for int type: Hello Morning
The main template fun(): 10.14 19.89
```

So what does the actual C++ Template Partial / Full specialization states - do we need to specify the data types in template argument to invoke - also in many websites I have seen following signature for Partial specialization:

```
template<class Y, const char*>
void fun(Y a, const char* b)
```

Rather than

```
template<class Y>
void fun(Y a, const char* b)
```

Similarly for full specialization - what is the exact way to write and call Partial / Full template specialized function / class?

Comment: Function templates can't be partially specialized. Also see: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/08/15/function-templates-partial-specialization-cpp/

Comment: That's not a partial specialization, that's an overload.

Comment: And see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061456/c-function-template-partial-specialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments cover the general principles, but there are specific questions here worth answering.  First, a lemma: the template parameters of a function template need not be **related** to its parameter types:

```
template<class T>
T make_1() {return T(1);}
auto v=make_1<std::vector<std::string>>(); // {""}
template<class T,class U>
void f(std::conditional_t<sizeof(T)<sizeof(U),int,long> i);
```

This is why your “partial specialization” is not a candidate for `fun<int, int>(…)`.  The template arguments aren’t just instructions for how to build the parameter list one by one, but rather must match the **actual** template parameters for the function template in question.  There’s only one of those, so they don’t match.  True partial specializations still use the primary template’s template parameter list; they just match against certain **patterns** in the list of arguments for it.

Meanwhile,

```
template<class Y, const char*>
void fun(Y a, const char* b)
```

is valid but doesn’t mean what you think for the same reason: `const char*` in the template parameter list introduces an **unnamed** (non-type) template parameter of type `const char*`, so that you’d have to use it like

```
char global;
void g() {fun<char,&global>('a',"foo");}
```

(with no deduction for `Y`!), only to have that `&global` ignored entirely,