# How can I hide a class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, visibility

Let's say I have 2 classes that I want to be visible (within a given header file) and one class that is their ancestor, which one I want to be visible only to the previously mentioned two. How can I achieve such class functionality of being invisible in C++?

Comment: Why? Just make it abstract so it can't be instantiated but serves as an interface. This is _useful_.

Comment: You could namespace them, but I'm pretty sure you couldn't make them completely inaccesible

Comment: I second what Lightness said, why would you want to?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe the functionality is templated.

Comment: @Seth: And so therefore?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and so therefore the templates can't be virtual and the class has to be in the header.

Comment: @Seth: Okay so back to the original question why try to hide it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't know, that's his business. Hiding private base classes maybe?

Comment: Rather than make the class an ancestor, you could make it a *contained* class, and use private implementation http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/making-pimpl-easy/205918714

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm still learning the OOP approach and it may indeed be a bad idea on my side, I've just thought it would be messy to declare simple classes globally that are of no use apart from inheritance. Haven't heard of abstract classes before, seems to be a suitable solution.

Comment: It's our business too if he is asking how to do it :)

Comment: The reason we ask why is because many times the problem is solved by going a different (better) direction altogether.

Comment: @JoshGreifer: I shudder when I read said code, especially since template specializations need be in the same namespace as the specialized template; it's horrendous :x

Comment: @obmarg: That's what I'd have said too. It doesn't even matter that being namespaced does not _truly_ make the class inaccessible. If you have a class in something like `namespace implementation` or `namespace detail` and some prick feels compelled to use it anyway just because it's technically possible, that's his own problem. You've made the intent clear, that's what counts. If it crashes and burns after they've abused your clearly stated intent, and they come complaining, just tell them to f... off.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well as for now your solution seems the most suitable for me. You could turn it to answer I guess.

Comment: Also see [Hide class type in header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3525552/608639), [How can I hide a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14092705/608639), [Hiding a C++ class in a header without using the unnamed namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5780918/608639)

Answer (score 12):

Abusing a `class` to act as a `namespace` will do this. I do not recommend this pattern.

```
class hidden_stuff {
private: // hide base from everyone
    struct base {
        // contents
    };
public:
    class derived1;
};
typedef class hidden_stuff::derived1 derived1;

class hidden_stuff::derived1
    : private hidden_stuff::base {}; // private inheritance required
            // or hidden_stuff::base is accessible as derived1::base
```

---

### The *real* solution (though not technically satisfying the question)

A preferable solution would be to use a clearly-named `namespace` such as `impl::` or `detail::`, which will convey to users that they shouldn't use any classes inside, and stop any possible undesired effects on overloading or the like. That's how most libraries (even Standard Library implementations) "hide" classes from the user.

Comment: I was kind of surprised to learn we could not use an unnamed namespace to hide classes in header files. It seems like the perfect tool (except its not allowed).

Comment: I like the subdivision into a separate namespace

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible.

C++ requires that a class be fully defined at the point it is used as a base, and because of its include mechanism anything that is fully defined at the point of definition of a class is necessarily visible to all who can see the definition of said class.

C++ has mechanisms to protect against Murphy (accidents) but not against Machiavelli (hacks).

---

That being said, the purpose is itself dubious, the only reason I can fathom would be to prevent the user from relying on the fact that your `Derived` class derives from this `Fantom` base. Well, deriving privately: `class Derived: private Fantom {};` or using composition instead `class Derived { private: Fantom _fantom; };` would both achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hiding class, I'd recommend diabling making use if it. In example:

```
class Hidden
{
  private:
    friend class Exposed;
    Hidden() {}
    int hidden_x;
};

class Exposed : private Hidden
{
  public:
    Exposed() : Hidden() {}
    void DoStuff() { printf( "%d" , hidden_x ); }
};
```

So what you can:
- create any number of Exposed class instances in your code
- call DoStuff() method from these instances

But you cannot:
- instantiate Hidden class (private constructor)
- operate on Hidden class members directly or via Exposed class (they are private)

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Anonymous answer, instead of private inheritance you can add private member of the hidden class.

```
class Hidden
{
   private:
      friend class Exposed;
      Hidden() {}
      int hidden_x;
};

class Exposed
{
  public:
      Exposed() {}
      void DoStuff() { printf( "%d" , hidden.hidden_x ); }
  private:
      Hidden hidden_;
};
```